# Speed up yarn install in Rails application docker build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github-actions, yarnpkg, yarn-v2

I have a Rails application that takes a bit too long to build.

During `rake assets:precompile` it seems to fire yarn to install some packages, this takes ages:

```
#22 11.04 yarn install v1.22.19
#23 11.18 [1/4] Resolving packages...
#23 11.96 [2/4] Fetching packages...
#23 27.46 [3/4] Linking dependencies...
#23 27.48 warning " > rails-erb-loader@5.5.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || >= 3.0.0-rc.0 || ^3.0.0".
#23 33.77 [4/4] Building fresh packages...
#23 249.9 Done in 238.92s.
```

Basically with every build 4 of my minutes are spent on this yarn install step over the following packages:

```
{
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actiontext": "^6.0.2-1",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "rails-erb-loader": "^5.5.2",
    "trix": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  }
}
```

I do need actiontext and trix. I do not use webpacker. I do have ERB assets (some dynamically generated JS).

I've removed as much dependencies as possible yet it still installs some 200Mb of gunk into node_modules which isn't a big deal as I'm cleaning up after it but it takes way too long to do that :(

Should I look into caching node_modules at docker build time?

Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: We've had success installing our gems and node packages in a Docker volume so they don't have to be re-installed every time you just want to start the container.

Comment: Thank you @Chiperific! Thing is this build is part of a CD pipeline serving several hosts so unless I'd do a nfs/EFS share I'd have no way to work this out... I'm already keeping all gems in an image I'm building in another stage so bundling only takes a few secs. The assets take ages tho :(